# Paypal Variables not Posting Correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal, asp.net-4.0, cart

I am building a completely custom shopping cart for a client, and the session("Payment_Amount") nor anything is posting to paypal. http://www.julianrycecreations.com/cprof/ucprof/store_front.aspx is where you can go to view her shopping cart. It is still in development and alot of things my not line up correctly. I can provide code if needed, but since this is custom and a shopping cart that my be limited but I will see what I can do. Thank you in advance.

this is the code that takes it to the checkout page order.aspx

```
 Protected Sub OrderBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OrderBtn.Click
    If OrderSummaryLit.Text = "" Then
        ErrorMessageLbl.Text = "Must Customize Product before Checkout."
    Else
        InsertOrderDS.Insert()
        Dim comm = db.selectcommand(db.conn, "TOP 1 column_name", "table_name", "column_name = '" & Session("session") & "' ORDER BY column_name DESC")
        Dim sqlda As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        sqlda.Fill(dt)
        Session("session") = dt.Rows(0)("column_name")
        Response.Redirect("order.aspx?ord_id=" & dt.Rows(0)("column_name"))
    End If
End Sub
```

here is the code for the button once you get the the order page. this uses and action that should send the session to the expresscheckout.aspx page provided by paypal. It should give an error or something but doesn't.

```
<form action='expresscheckout.aspx' method='post'>
```

Comment: Posting the code where you transmit your data to Paypal is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

What was causing the problem was not referencing the api code. I simply called the function from the expresscheckout and it worked.